# XMLHttpRequest error with React Native and Websockets (sockets.io)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, websocket, xmlhttprequest

I am having trouble getting React-Native working with sockets.io. I have a server with sockets.io running, and would like to connect through (the android version of) React-Native to this server. I cam currently getting the following error on execution however:

```
\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:63 Failed to set the 'responseType' property on 'XMLHttpRequest': The response type cannot be set after the request has been sent.
```

I'm not sure what relevant code to paste as it doesn't really give me a clue where it is failing, nor am I anywhere directly calling an XMLHttpRequest myself, but I suppose this is because it converts the socket io connection to XMLHttp. Though I am not 100% sure about this and it is simply something I picked up on online, it's a rather new topic for me.

Can anyone provide some insight into this?

Here is the full stack trace:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error is truncating which library this is coming from. That info could help us help you.

Comment: Absolutely right, that was silly of me. Updated and added the full stack trace :)

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, this was the solution.
I had to change from:

*const socket = io.connect(`${BASECONNECTION}:${PORT}`);*

to:

*const socket = io(`${BASECONNECTION}:${PORT}` **, { transports: ['websocket'] }**);*